# How do you remove repeated characters in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a website which allows users to comment on photos.
Of course, users leave comments like:

> 'OMGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'

or

> 'YOU SUCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK'

You get it.

Basically, I want to shorten those comments by removing at least most of those excess repeated characters.
I'm sure there's a way to do it with Regex..i just can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution... this changes the linguistics of the comment to something the author didn't intend. Basically they intended idiocy and you'll transform it to gibberish. For example when someone says "booooo!" will you transform it to "bo!"? What about numbers? Usernames? URLs?

Comment: You beter start shortening from thre repeating leters - doubled leters are al to comon in English.

Comment: Well typed idiotic spam is still idiotic spam, just slightly more difficult to spot at a glance.

Comment: Also see here for a clbuttic example of why this sort of thing is probably not a good idea: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

Comment: @Mark Pim: I would welcome well-typed comments even if they are intended as spam/flames.  Something like "YOU SSSUUUCCCKKK" should just be removed, but I wouldn't remove it if he'd said "I have observed and would like to indicate that you, sir, are a dunderhead and are singularly unworthy of any more of my time.  Good day to you."

Comment: How many repeated chars will you allow (i.e. "you suucckk" vs "you sssuuuccckkk" vs "you ssssuuuucccckkkk")? Or how about clusters of repeated chars like "LOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOL" or "s s s s s u u u u c c c c k k k k"?

Comment: @Juliet: Good point - Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V are the troll's best friends: "yousuckyousuckyousuck" is repetitive all right, yet wouldn't be caught. Perhaps check the entropy of the text - if it's too low, consider it repetititititive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keeping in mind that the English language uses double letters often you probably don't want to blindly eliminate them. Here is a regex that will get rid of anything beyond a double.

```
Regex r = new Regex("(.)(?<=\\1\\1\\1)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);

var x = r.Replace("YOU SUCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK", String.Empty);
// x = "YOU SUCCKK"

var y = r.Replace("OMGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", String.Empty);
// y = "OMGG!!"
```

Comment: Russian language sometimes uses triple letters (vary rarely), just FYI.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. It would be cool to augment the regex to know about a set of letters that are expected to be doubled or tripled up and  behave appropriately.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, your version leaves doubles.

Comment: @metabuddy read the question carefully. The ask was to remove most of the duplicates. Given the answer provided you should be able to make the necessary adjustment to remove all duplicates.

Answer (score 9):

Do you specifically want to shorten the strings in the code, or would it be enough to simply fail validation and present the form to the user again with a validation error?  Something like "Too many repeated characters."

If the latter is acceptable, `@"(\w)\1{2}"` should match characters of 3 or more (interpreted as "repeated" two or more times).

**Edit:** As @Piskvor pointed out, this will match on *exactly* 3 characters.  It works fine for matching, but not for replacing.  His version, `@"(\w)\1{2,}"`, would work better for replacing.  However, I'd like to point out that I think replacing wouldn't be the best practice here.  Better to just have the form fail validation than to try to scrub the text being submitted, because there likely will be edge cases where you turn otherwise readable (even if unreasonable) text into nonsense.

Comment: `(\w)\1{2,}`, I'd say. `(\w)\1{2}` would match exactly three characters.

Comment: @Piskvor: Are you certain?  I'm no regex expert by any means, but I just tested mine on "abbbbbbbcdef" and it matched.  (At least in .NET, which may even be exhibiting non-standard behavior but is the environment in question.)

Comment: Oh, it's going to *match* all right (as there *are* substrings with exactly three repetitions), it just won't match the whole duplication - note that it matches the bold part only: "a **bbb** bbbbcdef" . It's just not entirely convenient for doing a match *and replace*.

Comment: @Piskvor: Ah, I see your point now.  Though I definitely think that auto-replacing isn't the way to go here anyway.  (Your comment above illustrated one danger of it nicely.)  It's probably better practice to just kick the form back to the user as an invalid submission.

Comment: @David: Ah, good point - but I wouldn't match on 3 characters then, as I could imagine scenarios where they can be valid ("zooontology"? Perhaps not. "msoffice vs ooo"? Maybe.). Perhaps a more complex check would be needed?

Comment: @Piskvor: Agreed.  It's a quick and easy check for potential abuse (one of many to be performed), but it's by no means a complete solution.  It's a matter of ROI at that point, really.  Without a solid self-maintaining community it's up to the website's admin(s) to determine how much work to put into detecting undesirable input and try to get the most bang for their development buck.

Answer (score 1):

Regex would be overkill.
Try this:

```
public static string RemoveRepeatedChars(String input, int maxRepeat)
    {
        if(input.Length==0)return input;

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder;
        Char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
        Char lastChar = chars[0];
        int repeat = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<input.Length;i++){
            if(chars[i]==lastChar && ++repeat<maxRepeat)
            {
                b.Append(chars[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                b.Append(chars[i]);
                repeat=0;
                lastChar = chars[i];
            }
        }
        return b.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var nonRepeatedChars = myString.ToCharArray().Distinct().Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || !myString.Contains(c)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit : awful suggestion, please don't read, I truly deserve my -1 :)**

I found here on [technical nuggets](http://www.techienuggets.com/Detail?tx=203) something like what you're looking for.

There's nothing to do except a very long regex, because I've never heard about a regex sign for repetition ...

It's a total example, I won't paste it here but I think this will totally answer your question.

Comment: Aargh, that's horrible. Ääääääɫɫɫɫśśśśööööööö, this will only stop the blacklisted characters - not entirely useful now that Unicode is widely supported. Read about regex backreferences - they exist, even though you've never heard of them until now.

Comment: @Piskvor : Yes, I'm trying to look for them, but I can't find somewhere where it is explained. In fact, in the @"(\w)\1{2}", I don't understand what the \1 stands for. If you have a link where it's explained, that would be very useful for me :)

Comment: @LaGrandMere: I have no link handy, but the `\1` basically means that it's looking back at the first group in the regex (first set of parentheses), which is `(\w)`.

Comment: @David Many thanks for the explanation :) If anyone has a link, I would really be grateful !

Comment: uh ... typing `regex backreferences` into The Search Engine That Shall Not Be Named gave me "About 40,900 results" - the first hit explaining it quite clearly IMO (and links to exactly the kind of problem the OP posted: http://www.regular-expressions.info/duplicatelines.html ). Shortened: `(\w)` is the first capturing group (the match can be referenced further down the pattern), `\1` is the reference to this match, `{2}` matches the previous `\1` exactly 2 times (should be `{2,}` to match 2 or more times).

Comment: @Piskvor : Hahaha, I'm kind of confused with my poor participation in this post ... I think it's time for a cup of coffee or ... a good nap ! Thank you for your explanations :)

Comment: LaGrandMere: Don't worry, regex can be very confusing. I'm sorry if I haven't expressed myself clearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct() will remove all duplicates, however it will not see "A" and "a" as the same, obviously.

```
Console.WriteLine(new string("Asdfasdf".Distinct().ToArray()));
```

Outputs "Asdfa"

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = "OMMMMMGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGMMM";

test.Distinct().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList()
        .ForEach(c =>
            { 
                while (test.Contains(c + c)) 
                test = test.Replace(c + c, c); 
            }
        );
```