# Reduce multiple occurences of any non-alphanumeric characters in string down to one, **NOT REMOVE**

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been searching for a solution but almost every one that I've come across with is about replacing a matching pattern with a previously known character.
For example:

```
var str = 'HMQ 2.. Elizabeth';
```

How do we catch multiple occurences of that dots in the string and replace them with only one? And it's also **not specific to dots** but **any non-alphanumeric characters** that we don't know which. Thank you.

Comment: Something like this you mean? `(.)\1+` See https://regex101.com/r/nE4sH7/1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove repeated characters in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429995/how-do-you-remove-repeated-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: @M Sost yes but we don't know if it's going to be a dot. it can be any multiple non-alphanumerical character to be replaced with only one occurence of itself.

Comment: The period in the regex above is not a literal reference to a period. But yes, if you want non-alphanumerical chars, it would be `([^A-Za-z0-9])\1+`.

Comment: @M Sost yes I know that it's not but if the string had any multiple dashes, the one you suggested first was of no use. the last one works great. thank you.

Comment: @tchrist what's that? if you meant `/(\W)\1+/g`, that doesn't reduce underscores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a backreference. `\1` in the regex refers to the first match group in the expression.

```js
var str = 'HMQ 2.. Elizabetttth      .';

var regex = /([^A-Za-z0-9])\1+/g;

var trimmed = str.replace(regex, "$1");
console.log( trimmed );
```

Comment: thank you. and it's also possible with `/(.)\1+/g` as M Sost said in above comments, right? I also tried it and that worked the same. Actually at first it didn't because I forgot to put `g` at the end since he didn't mention it:)

Comment: No, if you use `/(.)\1+/g` with my example, you'll notice the multiple `t` characters reduced to 1, against your wishes. That's why I adjusted the sample string.