# Check a users comment for multiple extra letters added on to a banned word

Tags: c#

I want to filter some bad words like 'asshole' but you can bypass the word by just saying 'asssssshole' or 'asshoooole'

Here is my code currently.

```
string Word = "asshole";

if (Comment.Contains(Word)
    //block the comment from being posted
```

How would I check the message for multiple extra letters added on to a banned word, without creating hundreds of different rules for each way you can spell 'asshole'.

Comment: Filter for `a*s*h*o*l*e`?

Comment: The solution is regex study it then you create the rule as you wish for example the suggestion above, the problem now is that we can't give you a definite answer since we do not know the patterns you like to consider and the patterns you do not like to consider.

Comment: This for example is how to remove repeated characters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429995/how-do-you-remove-repeated-characters-in-a-string, which would cover the example's you made in your post.

Comment: Sounds like you're going to run into the [Scunthorpe Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) with this kind of thing.

Comment: It's **impossible**. As in **IMPOSSIBLE**. Humans are way too creative - you will **never** create a solution that cannot be bypassed by a human. Best you can do is filter from a fixed list of words and some simple modifications of them, to stop the casual abuse, but let's get rid of a pretense that your users, if they are so inclined, won't go around them. You should filter the **users who do this**, not content! Educate them or drop them if they can't be educated. Don't let a user know that they've been filtered: show their own post unchanged to them; replace the word with `*` for others.

Comment: In other words: look at how SO's moderation works. It's mostly a manual process, but eventually those who abuse the system get banned and that's the point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove repeated characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429995/how-do-you-remove-repeated-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: You can at best get some of them, it's an arms race and the looser you get in your matching the more likely you are to block "allowed" words, without ever eliminating all forms of the word.

Comment: I started with a comment about the Scunthorpe problem.  Follow the link @scott provided to see that.  I made the "clibuttic" mistake of not reading all the other comments. :)  [Clibuttic](https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)

Answer (score 2):

You might have some partial success using a soundex.  Try putting your variations into https://www.functions-online.com/soundex.html and they all return the same value `A240`, even `a*s*h*o*l*e`.  Unfortunately it won't work with `a$$hole`, but you might be able to come up with some simple substitutions to run before testing.

It should be pretty easy to find a c# implementation online.

Answer (score 0):

Make a regex out of it and check for a match:

```
//using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string word = "asshole";
//add a '+' after each letter to make it find any number of it
string pattern = string.Join("+", word.ToCharArray());
//pattern is "a+s+s+h+o+l+e"
if(Regex.IsMatch(comment, pattern))
{
    //do something
}
```